# How to configure the Tridion Monitoring Service?

Tags: content-delivery, configuration, monitoring

`cd_monitor_conf.xml` contains the entries:

```
<HeartbeatMonitoring ListenerPort="20131" EnableRemoteHeartbeats="true">
    <AutomaticServiceRegistration RegistrationFile="RegisteredServices.xml" />
    <Services>
        <Service ServiceType="SearchService"    TimeoutValue="10m" />
        <Service ServiceType="Search Indexer"   TimeoutValue="10m" />
        <Service ServiceType="Search Host"      TimeoutValue="10m" />
        <Service ServiceType="Publisher"        TimeoutValue="10m" />
        <Service ServiceType="WorkflowAgent"    TimeoutValue="10m" />
        <Service ServiceType="TransportService" TimeoutValue="10m" />   
    </Services>
</HeartbeatMonitoring>
```

And the entry:

```
<HttpServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="IIS" PollInterval="10m" TimeoutInterval="30s">
<Request URL="http://nlhdclabtcm.hinttech.local/WebUI/SplashScreen.html">
</HttpServiceHealthMonitor>
```

The Tridion Services defined in `cd_monitor_conf.xml` are running.

`cd_monitor.log` contains entries like this:

> 2013-03-14 00:00:16,361 INFO  IsAliveEventHandler - TMA-AG-10000
>   Monitoring agent is alive

and this:

> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,284 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service BusinessConnector - Health check failed. Status: HTTP/1.1 401
>   Unauthorized
>
> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,286 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service IIS - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>
> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,289 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service WorkFlowListener - Health check failed. Status: HTTP/1.1 401
>   Unauthorized
>
> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,294 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service WebDAV - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Why is there only one `IsAliveEventHandler - Monitoring agent is alive` event in the logfile?

Why are there no entries for the health of the WorkflowAgent or Publisher in the logfile?

I experimented with the tag:

```
<Authentication Scheme="NTLM" Host="NLHDCLABTCM" Domain="NLHDCLABTCM" Username="MTSUserAccount" Password="MTSUserPassword" />
<Authentication Scheme="Basic" Username="MTSUserAccount" Password="MTSUserPassword" />
```

Why does the monitor logfile show the following entries?

> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,284 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service BusinessConnector - Health check failed. Status: HTTP/1.1 401
>   Unauthorized
>
> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,286 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service IIS - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>
> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,289 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service WorkFlowListener - Health check failed. Status: HTTP/1.1 401
>   Unauthorized
>
> 2013-03-14 00:09:18,294 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001
>   Service WebDAV - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

On the server I can access those URL's with the MTSUserAccount/Password.

### Update 1

#### Version info:

Windows Server 2008 SP2 with SDL Tridion 2011

Content Manager Explorer - Build    6.1.0.55920

Content Manager - Build 6.1.0.996

Update Version - SP1

#### Configuration

The config.xml contains the element:

```
<HttpServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="IIS" PollInterval="10m" TimeoutInterval="30s">
<Request URL="http://nlhdclabtcm.hinttech.local/WebUI/SplashScreen.html"/>
<Authentication Scheme="NTLM" Username="myMTSaccount" Password="myPassword"/>
</HttpServiceHealthMonitor>
```

The Authentication element is shown without the Host or Domain attribute, but I have experimented with Host and Domain also, but this gives the same error.

Don't know what NTLMv1 is, I am using 2008SP2...

#### Authentication

In IIS Manager the WebUI folder has only Windows Authentication enabled, others like Basic Authentication is disabled.

#### Logfile

Now I do see the TMA-AG-99999 lines in the log. So this answers my question on how to see that the services are running.

2013-03-18 15:03:12,568 INFO  Server - TMA-SV-10000 Listening for connections on port 20132

2013-03-18 15:03:12,589 INFO  HeartbeatListener - TMA-HB-10000 Listening for heartbeats on port 20131

2013-03-18 15:03:14,592 INFO  ServiceStatusStore - TMA-AG-99999 Status of service 'Publisher' changed to OK

The other question is the authentication problem of e.g. the SplashScreen.

2013-03-18 15:04:13,125 INFO  AbstractHTTPHealthMonitor - TMA-PO-10001 Service IIS - Health check failed: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: what version/service pack of SDL Tridion are you using? Also can you check the XML of the configuration, I'm assuming the HttpServiceHealthMonitor has a element Request rather than the attribute as its seems now? Might be helpful if you edit the question yourself and make sure all the info provided is correct here, that helps us in helping you.

Comment: Three questions: 1. I hope in your config you have '<Request URL...' and not 'Request URL...'; 2. I hope your Request tag is properly closed in the config; 3. Can you find-out what NTLM version you're using for that monitored end-point? In 2011SP1 only NTLMv1 is supported.

Answer (score 4):

On my SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 installation I only have the HeartbeatMonitoring enabled, and that usually gives very little info in the cd_monitor_conf.xml logfile (log.level set to INFO in logback.xml).

> 2013-03-18 11:33:41,358 INFO  Agent - TMA-AG-10000 Loading configuration from cd_monitor_conf.xml
>
> 2013-03-18 11:33:41,490 INFO  Agent - TMA-AG-10000 Starting Tridion Monitoring Agent
>
> 2013-03-18 11:33:41,491 INFO  EventDispatcher - TMA-AG-10000 Event dispatcher has started
>
> 2013-03-18 11:33:41,494 INFO  Server - TMA-SV-10000 Listening for connections on port 20132
>
> 2013-03-18 11:33:41,509 INFO  HeartbeatListener - TMA-HB-10000 Listening for heartbeats on port 20131
>
> 2013-03-18 11:33:47,511 INFO  ServiceStatusStore - TMA-AG-99999 Status of service 'WorkflowAgent' changed to OK
>
> 2013-03-18 11:33:47,512 INFO  ServiceStatusStore - TMA-AG-99999 Status of service 'TransportService' changed to OK
>
> 2013-03-18 11:33:51,513 INFO  ServiceStatusStore - TMA-AG-99999 Status of service 'Publisher' changed to OK

I usually don't see log changes until I stop the service again (when testing it), and if left on long enough, you will see more if the `ServiceStatusStore` messages appear. Eventually also a couple of

> 2013-03-18 11:37:52,823 INFO  IsAliveEventHandler - TMA-AG-10000 Monitoring agent is alive

Messages will appear in my log, but with ta monitoring interval set at 10 minutes, it will might a while for all of those monitoring agents to be reported as online in the log it seems.

You could consider setting the log.level at DEBUG to see more information, I still found that unless some of the services are not responding or stopped, the logfile didn't always update instantaneously.